# apache virtual host presenting incorrect certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

One of my virtual hosts appears to be presenting the wrong certificate, using the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                        

        # Address                                                                         
        ServerName              git.mclarkdev.com                                         
        ServerAlias             158.69.115.69                         

        # Force Git                                                                       
        RewriteCond             %{HTTP_HOST} !^git\.mclarkdev\.com             [NC]       
        RewriteRule             ^ http://git.mclarkdev.com                     [R=301,L]  

        # Force Secure                                                                    
        RewriteCond             %{HTTPS}        !=on                                      
        RewriteRule             ^/?(.*)         https://git.mclarkdev.com/$1 [R,L]        
</VirtualHost>                                                                            

<VirtualHost *:443>                                                                       

        # Address                                                                         
        ServerName              git.mclarkdev.com                                         
        ServerAlias             158.69.115.69

        # Force Git                                                                       
        RewriteCond             %{HTTP_HOST} !^git\.mclarkdev\.com             [NC]       
        RewriteRule             ^ https://git.mclarkdev.com                     [R=301,L] 

        # Proxy Gogs                                                                      
        ProxyPass               /               http://git:3000/                          
        ProxyPassReverse        /               http://git:3000/                                                      

        # Certificates                                                                    
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/mclarkdev.com/git.mclarkdev.com.crt        
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/certs/mclarkdev.com/git.mclarkdev.com.key        
        SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/mclarkdev.com/git.mclarkdev.com.ca-bundle  

        # SSL Config
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH
        SSLProtocol -ALL -SSLv3 +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
        SSLHonorCipherOrder on
        SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck Off
        SSLCompression off
        SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire                                                                                                     
</VirtualHost>
```

The expected behavior here is as follows:

- User hits http://git.mclarkdev.com - redirected to https://git.mclarkdev.com
- User hits https://git.mclarkdev.com - served response as normal
- User hits http://158.69.115.69 - redirected to http://git.mclarkdev.com -
  redirects to https
- User hits https://158.69.115.69 - they are presented with a security warning for an invalid certificate, certificate and vhost being **git**.mclarkdev.com.

My issue now is that in the fourth use case, I am not presented with the certificate for `git`, but rather my root cert.

> This server could not prove that it is **158.69.115.69**; its security certificate is from **mclarkdev.com**.

The virtual hosts for my root domain are very similar to this, except for

```
ServerName              www.mclarkdev.com
ServerAlias             mclarkdev.com
```

Why would the git subdomain be presenting the root's certificate, despite having the IP address defined as an alias?

*Hitting the address and tailing logs, I am seeing entries for the request coming in via the root vhost*

*Running httpd on CentOS 7,
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

Server built:   Nov 14 2016 18:04:44*

Comment: If this would be more appropriate on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), please migrate.

Comment: how can a client get encrypted `Location` header with invalid certificate?

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with you having a loop.

Try changing in `<VirtualHost *:80>`, from:

`RewriteRule    ^ http://git.mclarkdev.com    [R=301,L]`

to

`RewriteRule    ^ https://git.mclarkdev.com    [R=301,L]`

notice the http**s**

Comment: I am not sure that will work as intended; the `Force Git` rule will match when a user navigates via IP, and will rewrite to `git.mclarkdev.com`, while the `Force Secure` rule will rewrite any insecure request, to secure. I will still have the same issue with the user being presented the wrong cert.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `158.69.115.69` as a `ServerAlias`. `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` should only list FQDN or wildcards (like `*domain.com`).

When accessing `158.69.115.69` you actually tap into the default vhost, or the global Apache conf, but not the `git.mclarkdev.com` vhost.

You then get the default server cert, for `mclarkdev.com`, and of course your rewrite rule is not applied because it's only defined in the other vhosts.

You should add this rule to the default vhost to make sure the rest happens in the 2 vhosts you're sharing here.

You could also change the vhosts order and make sure your 2 `git.mclarkdev.com` vhosts are defined before the `mclarkdev.com` one. In this case, it would become the default one and access it the IP would actually be like accessing `git.mclarkdev.com`.

If you use a `sites-enabled` like distro config, you can rename the symbolic links (for example, rename your vhosts files `000-something`) to make sure they are included first. As a matter of facts, the default vhost is usually called `000-default` for this specific reason, and you'll probably need to rename it too.

> PS: note that despite doing all that you might still get a `This
>   server could not prove that it is 158.69.115.69; its security
>   certificate is from git.mclarkdev.com.` warning before the redirect,
>   simply because https is not meant to be accessed via IP. Certificates
>   are name based only.